# RoR user add via JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, json, post

We receive json-object via POST with format {email,password,hash,currentDate,companyName}

Needs to create user in our DB (postrege) using RoR methods.

Please, help to realize that method.

Comment: Paste the exact JSON data you are receiving via POST method.

Comment: {email:'example@example.com',password:'passexp',hash:'abc',currentDate:'23.04.2012',companyName:'Test_company'}

Comment: what is the value of params in controller?
puts params.inspect in your controller action name and paste the output.

Comment: I'm newby in RoR in general. I have no controller right now. Just need to understood how it works.

Comment: Anyway, tnx you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read the [JSON/XML parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-xml-parameters) part of the "Action Controller Overview" rails guide. Maybe you can't modify the JSON you get and you have to look at the `config.wrap_parameters` option.

If you receive a JSON object like

```
{"user" : {"email": "user@example.com",
           "password": "secret",
           "hash": "sd98ds789fsd",
           "currentDate": "the-current-date",
           "companyName": "Umbrella corp."}}
```

You'll find it in the params hash as always:

```
# This will be "user@example.com"
params[:user][:email]
# This will contain "secret"
params[:user][:password]
```

Comment: {email:'example@example.com',password:'passexp',hash:'abc',currentDate:'23.04.2012',companyName:'Test_company'}